# How to check and see if a value in rows below is less than the current row value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a conditional column (We will call it "Y/N"), to test and see if a value in all rows below have a value that is greater than the current row value. If so, the binary "Y/N" column would return "Y". It also needs to check and see if any of the rows below have the same ID. In this case it will be sorted by ID. Here is an example dataframe, some code I would apply but will not capture all rows below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[223, 225, 225, 228, 230, 235, 235, 235, 235, 240, 241, 241, 241, 242], 'Value':[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0})
```

Attempted code is below. The issue with it is that I could only call for the row below and want to call on all rows below the current one to see if there is an instance where the ID below equals the current row ID and that there is a value below that is greater than the current row value.

```
cond_ID = df['ID'] == df['ID'].shift(-1)
cond_Value = df['Value'] < df['Value'].shift(-1)
df['Y/N'] = np.where((cond_ID) & (cond_value), 'Y', 'N'))
```

Desired Outcome:

```
df_outcome = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[223, 225, 225, 228, 230, 235, 235, 235, 235, 240, 241, 241, 241, 242], 'Value':[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0], 'Y/N':['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N']})
```

Comment: Can you explain more about when does the 'Y/N' value become 'Y' with the example code?

Comment: do you need to check all the values for the ID, below the current to check if any of the value below is higher?

Comment: "How to check and see if a value in rows below is less than the current row value" and "all rows below have a value that is greater than the current row value" one contradicts the other.  According to the expected result, where Y is after 3, 2, you can still understand that after them there are more values. Then why in other cases N.

Comment: @jaemmin, the Y would take place when the same 'ID' below has a Value' that is greater than its own 'Value'. In this case 'ID': 235 with 'Value': 3 would have a 'Y' because it has another ID beneath it and a 'Value' of 4 underneath. 4 is greater than 3, so it would be a 'Y'. Same goes for 2 right underneath it, the 2 for 235 would have a 'Y' because it has a 4 beneath it. Does that make sense?

Comment: @inquirer see response of mine above if it helps clarify.

Comment: @DekeMarquardt answered, check.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_func(x):
    ind = (df.loc[x.index[0]:, 'ID'] == x['ID'].values[0]) & (df.loc[x.index[0]:, 'Value'] > x['Value'].values[0])
    dff = df[x.index[0]:]
    if len(dff[ind]) > 0:
        return 'Y'
    else:
        return 'N'

df.loc[:, 'Y/N'] = df.groupby(df.index).apply(my_func)

print(df)
```

The my_func Function takes slices starting from the current index:

```
x.index[0]:
```

Conditions are checked by 'ID' and 'Value'. The rest of the dataframe is retrieved by slice, a boolean mask is substituted. If the dataframe is not empty, then there is such data:

```
if len(dff[ind]) > 0:
```

Output

```
     ID  Value Y/N
0   223      0   N
1   225      1   N
2   225      0   N
3   228      0   N
4   230      0   N
5   235      3   Y
6   235      2   Y
7   235      4   N
8   235      1   N
9   240      0   N
10  241      2   N
11  241      0   Y
12  241      1   N
13  242      0   N
```